# Cookies login doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, cookies, c#-4.0, asp.net-membership, cookiestore

I have a problem. I have done custom "Remember Me" functionality using cookies.

```
 HttpCookie rememberMeCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(userName, rememberMe);
 if (rememberMe)
 {
     rememberMeCookie.Expires = Controller.LocalizationProvider.GetAdjustedServerTime().AddMonths(6);
 }

 HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(rememberMeCookie);
```

I see the cookie in firecookies tools in the Firefox. It exists and has the correct expiration date.
But when I changed time - moved to next month. After that I entered to the site and I unlogged user. If I return to present time - I became authothication user.

Answer (score 1):

May be [formsauthentication timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx) in your web.config is interferring. Here is what MSDN has to say:

> Under ASP.NET V1.1 persistent cookies
>   do not time out, regardless of the
>   setting of the timeout attribute.
>   However, as of ASP.NET V2.0,
>   persistent cookies do time out
>   according to the timeout attribute.